# Pip install Killed

Tags: python, django, pip, python-wheel

Every time when I try to install some package, I get:

```
(ecz) root@zakazatdostavku:/opt# pip install django gunicorn
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 6.9MB 11.6MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

Here is the link on `--verbose` version
https://github.com/AnSharipov/restrict-same-words/blob/a4b2b4ed47c376ca15bbc19569e72cd3a4533292/log

Comment: This look like an OOM kill. Can you provide some details about the hardware on which you try to run this command and the amount of memory available.

Comment: Please check `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log` for any hint. It could possibly be Out of Memory issue or something. Please check

Comment: Also check this virtualenv and root again. Try installing it with sudo, Whats the result?

Comment: I didnt find any suitable logs in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log`. When run `pip install package` over sudo I get the same error - Killed

Comment: @AjaySingh Got input from `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` Out of memory: Kill process 16044 (pip) score 57 or sacrifice child

Comment: @Mr.Freeman : try to reinstall and if you didn't get any success, try to swap some memory https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @AjaySingh the problem was in RAM. I cleaned memory and everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I had this issue and it was an OOM problem. Increased the size of my VM and all worked fine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had to increase free RAM. After that everything works fine

Comment: Thank you. I have met same trouble when I was trying to install Tensorflow. About 2Gb RAM was allocated before and it was increased to 4 GB  on my virtualbox machine and the package was installed fine.

Comment: It was the same for me, installing "huggingface transformers" fails with 2GB and succeeds with 4GB on VirtualBox.